# Unitialised value(s) using valgrind

Tags: c, byte, valgrind

I'm running valgrind and I'm getting the following error..
before I made a backup I fixed it but now I don't remember how. Error was generated by malloc but I can't find the error in the code

```
>Insert password for admin: ==5720== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5720==    at 0x40299EB: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:538)
==5720==    by 0x80496C6: adm_log_request (commands_man.c:169)
==5720==    by 0x80521CA: main (mmboxman.c:9)
==5720==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5720==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==5720==    by 0x8049683: adm_log_request (commands_man.c:165)
==5720==    by 0x80521CA: main (mmboxman.c:9)
==5720==
```

This is the function
The line commands_man: 165 is that after if(size > 0)

```
int adm_log_request(void){

FILE *password;
char *pwdin, *frompwd = NULL;
int primo = 0/*indica se è un primo avvio*/, tentativi = 2, p, size;

if(!(password = fopen(F_PWD_ADM, "rb"))){
    primo = 1;
    printf("First server boot\n>Insert password for admin: ");
}
else{
    primo = 0;
    printf(">Insert password for admin: ");
}
p = get_hid_pass(&pwdin);
if(p < 0)
    return -1;
switch(primo){
    case 0:
        if(!(password = fopen(F_PWD_ADM, "r")))
            return -1;
        fread(&size, sizeof(int), 1, password);
        if(size > 0){
            frompwd = (char*)malloc(size + 1);
            fread(frompwd,sizeof(frompwd),1,password);
        }else return 0;
        while(tentativi > 0){
            if(strcmp(pwdin, frompwd) != 0){
                printf("\nIncorrect password\n%d attempts left\n>Insert password for admin: ", tentativi);
                tentativi--;
            }
            else return 1;
            p = get_hid_pass(&pwdin);
            if(p < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        fclose(password);
        break;
    case 1:     //primo avvio del server
        if(!(password = fopen(F_PWD_ADM, "w")))
            return -1;
        size = strlen(pwdin) + 1;
        fwrite(&size, sizeof(int), 1, password);
        fwrite(pwdin, sizeof(pwdin), 1, password);
        fclose(password);
        break;
}
if(tentativi == 0)
    return -1;

return 1;
}
```

Could someone help me to fix them?? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem looks like an issue with `sizeof`:

```
        fread(frompwd,sizeof(frompwd),1,password);
```

In the above line, sizeof will have a value of 4 (assuming 32-bit architecture).  It may be that you need to pass in `size` for the length.  And then it still needs to be null terminated after that.

```
frompwd[size] = '\0';
```

The `fwrite` call has a similar problem and will only write 4 bytes of the password.

Comment: I find the problem..it was in
    size = strlen(pwdin) + 1;

+1 was wrong!! Thanks!! =)

Comment: @roccocullo: It depends if you are wanting to write the null terminator byte or not.  And note that the `fwrite` call still needs to be given the correct length (size) instead of the sizeof results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `fread` doesn't actually set `size` to anything?

It's not guaranteed that it will. See its return value (from [the man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fread/)):

> RETURN VALUES
>
> The functions fread() and fwrite() advance the file position indicator
>        for the stream by the number of bytes read or written.  They return the
>        number of objects read or written.  If an error occurs, or the end-of-
>        file is reached, the return value is a short object count (or zero).
>
> The function fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error;
>        callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.  The
>        function fwrite() returns a value less than nitems only if a write error
>        has occurred.

If the return value is for example 0, then `size` is still uninitialized in line `165`. A good practice would be to check what `fread` returns and confirm that the value was actually read successfully.

Answer (score 0):

First you read 4 bytes (or 8 on 64-bit) from a file:

```
fread(frompwd,sizeof(frompwd),1,password);
```

You probably didn't mean to use `sizeof(frompwd)` here.

Then you, compare using strcmp:

```
strcmp(pwdin, frompwd)
```

`strcmp` carries on comparing until one of the two strings contains a nul '\0' character. In this case you never nul-terminated your password string, hence the message.

You should a) use the right read size, and b) use `strncmp` to make sure you don't get buffer-overrun errors like this one.

Comment: Don't forget to allocate space for the nul-terminator. You need string size plus 1.